# How to set the number of rings in a sunburst?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to create a sunburst that has only 2-3 levels. I stumbled upon this question [How to hide outer ring in zoomable sunburst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190077/how-to-hide-outer-ring-in-zoomable-sunburst/28851516?noredirect=1#comment45978040_28851516) , but in this example (http://protembla.com/wheel.html) if I hide "who is working on the tasks." and then I select Natasha it doesn't display the arc with the time label.

How can I create a sunburst that has a fixed number of rings but is still able to display the data that initially is hidden when someone clicks on an arc?

Comment: You would need to modify the data appropriately; this isn't something that's supported by the API.

Comment: Can I load another json dynamically? For example if I click a button I want the new data to replace the old one.

Comment: Yes, sure. You can run arbitrary code.

Comment: Do you have an example for this? I want to be able to replace the original data with a new one when I click a button.

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html).